# Is it possible to reuse openapi models from other files?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, openapi-generator

I have a simple kotlin backend app that exposes own swagger api and consumes external api using it's swagger docs. During build time I generate several api models using gradle `openapi-generator` plugin.

As an example - I've configured two tasks that generate models for:

1. Application swagger docs:

```
task<GenerateTask>("application") {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("${rootProjectOpenapiFolder.resolve("application-swagger.yaml")}")
    packageName.set("org.foo")
    outputDir.set("${buildDir.resolve("generated/openapi")}")
}
```

2. Auxilary api1:

```
task<GenerateTask>("api") {
    generatorName.set("kotlin")
    inputSpec.set("${rootProjectOpenapiFolder.resolve("api1.yaml")}")
    packageName.set("org.bar")
    outputDir.set("${buildDir.resolve("generated/openapi")}")
}
```

Then I expose application's api using customized swagger-ui file location:

```
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
  swagger-ui:
    url: /application-swagger.yaml
```

But further I face a problem with model duplication...

Example:

External service uses a schema:

```
...
components:
  schemas:
    Baz:
      type: string
      enum:
        - first
        - second
```

There is no problem to use it internally, because an appropriate model will be generated in:
`build/generated/openapi/org/bar/model/models/Baz`

The thing is that I need also to expose this model within application's api. But `application's` specification knnows nothing about that model. Besides, I need to keep the exposed api clean, so specification merge is not a good solution.

The thing I need - make some models, like `Baz` be generated in a separate output and be used on each openapi-generator tasks.

Is there any way to handle these common models so, that they could be used by all generated models??